# Can i use Model or Helper function in routes.php [codeigniter]

Tags: codeigniter

I wants to set database values to the URL.
Actually i have ID of product so that i wants to show its Name by fetching from database.
Currently i am passing integer ID through URL so that i wants a name of that ID related Product.

My current  URL is  like : http://example.com/controller/method/1
I wants URL like : http://example.com/controller/method/product-name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the last bit in the url as an argument to the method of your controller class.

```
class myClass extends CI_Controller {
    public function myMethod ( $product )
    { echo $product; }
}
```

This will result in url : `http://example.com/myClass/myMethod/anything_goes_here`

And in your controller method `myMethod` the argument `$product` will be the last part of the above url `anything_goes_here`

For this example, the echo in the `myMethod` will produce result `anything_goes_here`

This doesn't need rerouting.

If you are getting the products based on names then this solution will do, but I don't think this will be good in real life situation. For example what if you have more then one product with the same name ?

If you still want to use product name, then I think the following approach is better. Where you will use get request uri.

```
class myClass extends CI_Controller {
    public function myMethod ( $product )
    { echo $this->input->get ( 'id' ); echo $product; }
}
```

And use the url like this : `http://example.com/myClass/myMethod/anything_goes_here?id=123`

In the above url, the `?id=123` is the get uri. This way you can have both the product name and the id of the product in the url.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i guess u are  using id as parameter in controller method.
class example extends CI_Controller {
    public function method ( $product_name )
    { echo $product_name; }
}

this will give u product_name as last field in controller as like controller/method/product_name..